# Difference between HostnameVerifier and DefaultHostnameVerifier

Tags: java, ssl, jax-ws, httpsurlconnection

I am implementing a hostname verifier for my SSL client. I know that the Default Hostname Verifier of the HTTPS URL connection is static. My problem is that I do not want the hostname verification to be static because I have multiple threads in my client accessing this hostname verifier at the same time.

At the moment my code looks like this,:

I have an inner class for the hostname verification,

```
public class CreateHostnameVerifier implements HostnameVerifier {
    @Override
    public boolean verify(String hostname, SSLSession session) {

            try {
                if (mInstance.getHost().equals(InetAddress.getByName(hostname)))
                    return true;
                else if (hostname.equals(mInstance.getHost().getHostAddress()))
                    return true;
                else if (hostname.equals(mInstance.getHost().getCanonicalHostName()))
                    return true;
                else
                    return false;

            } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
                System.out.println("Unknown Host");
            }
            return false;
        } 
    }
}
```

I call this class when I am building my endpoint,

```
address = mInstance.getSecureConnectionEndpoint();
try {
        HttpsURLConnection Connection = (HttpsURLConnection) address.openConnection();
        CreateHostnameVerifier hv = new CreateHostnameVerifier();
        Connection.setDefaultHostnameVerifier(hv);
        } catch (IOException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Because I use `setDefaultHostnameVerifer` and try to access it in a non static way by doing `Connection.setDefaultHostnameVerifier` I get warnings like:

```
The static method setDefaultHostnameVerifier(HostnameVerifier) from the type HttpsURLConnection should be accessed in a static way
```

But this works absolutely fine, but in case I try to access it in a non-static way:

```
Connection.setHostnameVerifier(hv);
```

It does not work. 
Can someone explain me the difference between the two, i.e., `setHostnameVerifer` and `setDefaultHostnameVerifier`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> My problem is that I do not want the hostname verification to be static because I have multiple threads in my client accessing this hostname verifier at the same time.

This "requirement" is based on a misapprehension.

There is nothing *per se* wrong with multiple threads using the same `HostnameVerifier`.  Unless you do something very strange, one of these objects should have no mutable state.  Provided that your shared object `HostnameVerifier` instance is safely published (and immutable), it can be safely used by multiple threads without any need for synchronization.

---

> Can someone explain me the difference between the two, i.e., `setHostnameVerifier` and `setDefaultHostnameVerifier`.

The javadoc for [`HttpsURLConnection.setHostnameVerifier`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/net/ssl/HttpsURLConnection.html#setHostnameVerifier-javax.net.ssl.HostnameVerifier-) explains it:

> `public void setHostnameVerifier(HostnameVerifier v)`
>
> Sets the `HostnameVerifier` for this instance.  New instances of this class inherit the default static hostname verifier set by `setDefaultHostnameVerifier`. Calls to this method replace this object's `HostnameVerifier`.

One possible reason that `setHostnameVerifier` is not working for you may be that you are calling it too late; i.e. after the connection has been established, and the verification has been performed.

---

The way to avoid the warning is to set the default verifier like this:

```
    HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultHostnameVerifier(hv);
```

It is a static method, so it *should* be called via the class name not via an instance reference.  (That's what the warning is telling you ...)

Comment: I also found out that in JAX-WS you cannot overwrite the default hostname verifer directly, you need to set it in the request context of JAXWS Properties like 
`context.put(JAXWSProperties.HOSTNAME_VERIFIER,new myHostnameVerifer);`